# Audio having cracking sound when played in a timeline

Tags: unity-game-engine

The audio is fine when played outside the timeline. I have tried ogg, wav and mp3 file formats, I have tried pretty much every combination of the import settings and also tried exporting the audio file in different quality settings but this problem still persists across all devices I have tried it on. Thanks in advance!

Unity Version - 2021.1.21f1

Comment: Could you show us your settings etc everything relevant for reproducing the issue?

Comment: @derHugo thanks for the reply,

Audio Import Settings -

- Force To Mono - False
- Normalize - True
- Load In Background - False
- Ambisonic - False
- Load Type - Decompress on load
- Preload Audio Data - True
- Compression Format - Vorbis
- Quality - 100
- Sample Rate Setting - Preserve Sample Rate

Comment: @derHugo One thing to note is that the issue only happens when timeline is played in the scene. It is fine when I want to play it in the editor.

Comment: I think we would be more interested in the settings you have in your timeline, your code that is playing it etc ... ;)

Comment: @derHugo the Update Method in PlayableDirector was set to Game time, changing it to DSP clock fixed the issue :-D

Answer (score 0):

Apparently setting the Update Method parameter in PlayableDirector to Game Time caused this issue. I set it back to DSP clock and it fixed the issue.

Documentation -
https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.1/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayableDirector.html